# In Storyboard my UITableView is at top of page, in app it's not

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

Using Storyboard I have my UITableView drawn starting at the top of my ViewController and as wide and tall as the VC. When i run my app it lowers the UITableView roughly 75 pixels. I've tried to turn on/off auto layout and every auto-sizing option imaginable. I've tried changing the device toggle from iphone 5 to 4. I've tried adding support to rotate the interface just to rule that out too.

The only way i can make the table stay at the top of the page is to manually edit the UITableView's origin frame in my viewDidLoad statement.

```
//myTable is the UITableView in question
CGRect newFrame = self.myTable.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 0;
newFrame.origin.y = 0;
self.myTable.frame = newFrame;
```

I am using xCode 4.6.1. Anybody else have this problem and know a solution? Thanks!

[image: Here's a screenshot to illustrate the space i am speaking of]

Comment: That was my first thought as well, @waf. Where does the segue arrow pointing to your view originate from? All the best

Comment: i know the screen shot doesn't reflect this, but the View Controller is the root controller (I moved the storyboard accidentally when taking this screen shot). I don't have a nav controller in my app but i do remember that bottom tool bar defaulting to the top a couple of times when i was moving it around. My guess is this is a storyboard bug. I deleted the table and connected a new one same as the last and it works now, thanks for the advice! Still like to know if anyone else knows how to fix this w/o creating a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Enable autolayout.
Select table
At the bottom right. By the arrows in The interface builder set the border to top of superview (a little button that looks like it has an H in it)

Comment: thanks, but no change. Also my project won't work with autolayout turned on due to another ViewController.

Comment: Do you have a root navigation controller for this view? That space just looks oddly perfect for a nav bar

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your tableView size is as per in my attached Image.

```
**//Do your tableView frame size in viewWillAppear**

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   CGRect newFrame = self.myTable.frame;
   newFrame.origin.x = 0;
   newFrame.origin.y = 0;
   self.myTable.frame = newFrame; 
 }
```

[Sample Image](http://postimage.org/image/7sf36jc0b/b8403950/)

Hopes its useful for you..:)